# App crashes on BluetoothManager#getConnectedDevices() call

Tags: java, android

I want to programm an App, that checks wheter a device is connected or not. I use the method getConnecctedDevices(). But everytime I run it, it crashes. 
I use this:

```
private BluetoothManager BM;
private List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices;
connectedDevices=BM.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothGatt.GATT_SERVER);
```

Why?
Thank you

Comment: Because you did not assign a value to `BM`and so you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_03_005.htm#mj21b86db09c28ddf9b92b692620c00cdb) will help you to solve your issue